# android studio is not able to recognize my device

Tags: android-studio, flutter, usb-drive

I am using Flutter for developing my android apps but for some my android studio is not able to recognize my device even though my device is detecting that fully. Is there a way to fix this?

And also for the record, I have tried all the possible methods available on stack overflow and internet like Enabling USB debugging, MTP Transfer, Installing universal USB Driver.

Answer (score 0):

Some phones like OPPO, VIVO, etc is having an extra drivers. It will be shown when you connect your phone with pc. You have to install that driver too. Also check whether this phone is working with another computer or any other phones works in your computer too(to check both your phone and PC is ok). Also check in normal android app development instead of flutter, like checking your phone connection in android studio with java or kotlin.
if all this didn't works then install Visual Studio Code and check the same thing it it. may be this is some issues in Android studio. please inform the details here after all this.

Answer (score 0):

Go to file> Invalidate cache/Restart > click invalid cache and restart button in android studio.
Then run.
If still cannot connect device:
goto file>settings> appearance & behaviour > Android SDK > sdk tools >deselect android sdk platform tools > apply>ok.
It installed the requested components.
then goto app > edit configuration> uncheck allow parallel run in right corner>ok